# Temporary table will not drop

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado, temp-tables, drop-table

The conditional drop table line in the code below doesn't seem to work. It executes without error, but then the next line errors saying the object ID already exists - so it's not actually dropping the table.

Any ideas?

I'm connecting to an MS SQL Server 2005 database through OLE DB (SQLOLEDB provider) using ADO.

```vb
'Create a temporary table on the SQL Server and insert into it the info for the end part
With ADOcmA
    Set .ActiveConnection = mObjCON
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('" & TEMPTABLE & "') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE " & TEMPTABLE
    .Execute
    .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " & TEMPTABLE & " (ITEM VARCHAR(255),DESCRIP1 CHAR(255),DESCRIP2 CHAR(255), LEV INT, SEQ VARCHAR(255), FLAG1 TINYINT, PRIMARYKEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,QTY_PER FLOAT)"
    .Execute
    .CommandText = "Insert Into " & TEMPTABLE & " (ITEM,DESCRIP1,DESCRIP2,LEV,SEQ,FLAG1,QTY_PER) select item_no,Item_desc_1,Item_desc_2,1,1,'1',1 FROM " & cstrMACtItem & " WHERE Item_no ='" & strITEM & "' "
    .Execute
End With
```

FWIW the temptable name is created at runtime using the format `#[WSID]TEMP[NOW]` and truncated to 116 characters, so for example:`TEMPTABLE=#LOKSPEC1TEMP141031155408`

Also, I've tried escaping the table name using single quotes or double quotes but always same result (it doesn't drop). I found square brackets raise a syntax error.

Comment: Apparently, since your question is marked as a duplicate, I cannot add an answer, but the simple answer is that you are trying to drop a session-local temp table (one #-prefix, e.g. #tmp), as opposed to a global temp table (two #-prefix, e.g. ##tmp), and these are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql creates tables prefaced with the pound sign in a whole other place than your current working database.  So if you want to interrogate schema information of a temp table, then you need to explicitly reference that other database.  It might be easier to see if you tweaked your code like this

```
.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.." & TEMPTABLE & "') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE " & TEMPTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your temp table drop query to this

```
 CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.." & TEMPTABLE & "') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE " & TEMPTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another approach that works by looking in the same `tempdb` location.

```
.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '" & TEMPTABLE & "%') DROP TABLE " & TEMPTABLE
.Execute
```

Comment: Yeah, this one is interesting because of the wildcard there.  Temp tables like this are session specific.  Another user might come along and create a temp table with a name like yours, and SQL avoids a name collision by appending a whole bunch of other junk that keeps the two tables unique and qualifies them a bit.  It's imaginable that this query could return an id for a table similar to yours but created in a different session.  It is crazy unlikely, but it will be damn near impossible to figure out what happened if it ever does.